Is it treasonous for government officials to continue to report to those unfit for service?
If a colonel knows that a general is unfit for service due to age and cognitive decline, is it treasonous for the colonel to report to said general as the communications may contain sensitive and secret information.
Do the circumstances change substantially if it is not within the uniform code of military justice?

It is both a very bad idea and impossible for a lower ranked member to judge a higher ranked member like that. There are reporting channels in the military for such concerns but they come with risk to the person doing the reporting.

This seems to be a Q about what the law is, so probably best suited to Law SE. It's probably not remotely treason but perhaps one can make an argument that it's mishandling classified info by disclosing them to someone not in full command of their faculties. OTOH it's a risky argument because of the chain of command etc.

Maybe less treason than grounds for court-martial?  Which may then acquit or condemn the colonel.  Militaries in general take very dim views of "underlings knowing better".  VTC  question does not appear to be about governments, policies and political processes  The appropriate action would probably be for the colonel to report their concerns to the appropriate military channel.

Most communications probably don't involve disclosing sensitive information to the senior officer.

@Barmar That's a good point. How often does sensitive information flow up the chain of command? Typically superiors are the ones that disseminate sensitive information.

@Barmar Information is disclosed to superior officers by their subordinates and other lower ranked members of the military through reports, briefings, etc.  The superior officers aren't the ones looking at satellite photos, listening to wiretaps, or on the ground.

I vaguely remember reading somewhere about a military person (not sure if they were in charge of nuclear weapons) who was wondering about when he can refuse an order. The standard protocol only gave a procedure for verifying that the order is legit. It did not give a procedure for verifying that the superior who issued the order is sane. When he raised the issue, he didn't receive a clear response. Don't remember the ending of that story (he may have been forced into another line of work).

@IllusiveBrian I'm not saying that this doesn't happen, just that it's not most of the communications. Certainly when underlings are responsible for data gathering, much of the data will be sensitive. But there's also lots of communication that doesn't involve reporting this data.


Is it treasonous for government officials to continue to report to
those unfit for service

No.
Article III, Section 3, Clause 1 of the U.S. Constitution, also known as the Treason Clause, states that treason consists of:

Levying war against the United States

Adhering to the enemies of the United States

Giving aid and comfort to the enemies of the United States.


Reporting a superior officer's health does not constitute treason.
Not all acts the undermine a superior officer are treason. Indeed, it would be the vanishingly rare exception when they are treason. If the acts were taken through the proper channels, it would not be an offense or crime at all.
Likewise, as the language of the question is somewhat ambiguous, it is not illegal to disobey an unlawful order (even under the Uniform Code of Military Justice) and even if one does disobey a lawful order, this is an offense far less serious than treason (particularly if the order is disobeyed without an intent to aid an enemy).
Obeying lawful orders is required under the Uniform Code of Military Justice even if the good judgment of the person giving the orders is doubted by the subordinate. But disobeying a clearly unlawful order is mandatory.
One could also view the question as asking if it is treason to pass secrets to a superior officer when that superior officer could act improperly "due to age and cognitive decline." Again, this clearly isn't treason, and again, usually a subordinate does not make this call. It would only be a concern if there was good reason to believe that the general was, for example, plotting a coup or had been compromised by an enemy spy, which could cause imminent harm (there is a legal duty to report suspected treason and sedition and it is crime to fail to do so).
Further, doubt as to the competency of the Commander-in-Chief is not a lawful basis, in and of itself, for a subordinate to the Commander-in-Chief in the military to ignore the Commander-in-Chief's orders, unless the particular orders in question are believed to be unlawful for some reason.

This doesn't seem to be what the Q is asking though "is it treasonous for the colonel to report to said general ass the communications may contain sensitive and secret information".

The question doesn't seem be asking about reporting the situation to another higher ranking officer (or some reporting process) rather interacting with the officer in question.

@JoeW The question is indeed ambiguous as both comments point out. I've explored other interpretations of it in edits to the answer.

The edits make sense.

There are rules how subordinates can relieve a superior, especially applicable to ships at sea. It used to be section 1088, and the WWII situation was showcased in the movie The Caine Mutiny with Bogart. They do not involve keeping the superior in position and restricting information flow.

FWTW, the DoD does put substantial onus on the person making the disclosure:

The individual with authorized possession,
knowledge, or control of the information has the final responsibility for determining whether a
prospective recipient’s official duties requires them to possess or have access to any element or
item of classified information, and whether that prospective recipient has been granted the
appropriate security clearance by proper authority.

However, I'd be really impressed if anyone was ever prosecuted or otherwise penalized for doubting that the "prospective recipient has been granted the
appropriate security clearance by proper authority" when they've seen the proper paperwork. Doubting the competence of a superior is not outside the realm of action allowed for military officers, but the subordinate would be expected to file some [possibly whistleblower] complaint with the proper authority [perhapsy ultimately with the DoD OIG, for uniformed personnel] in such cases. (Remember how the 1st Trump impeachment case started, for instance, although lack of cognitive capacity was not the alleged issue then.)
Deciding [e.g.] that the President lacks "the appropriate security clearance by proper authority" is tantamount to deciding they are not president (because the POTUS can't be 'unauthorized' otherwise), which would be extremely risky for the average uniformed officer to do single-handedly, given the provisions of the 25th amendment which put such a decision with the [majority of the] cabinet as the 'proper authority' in this case. And if the president contests that, it's up to Congress to decide.


Does the circumstances change substantial if it is not within the uniform code of military justice?

Probabably no. The equivalent in law applicable to everyone is likely 18 U.S. Code § 798:

Whoever knowingly and willfully communicates, furnishes, transmits, or otherwise makes available to an unauthorized person, or publishes, or uses in any manner prejudicial to the safety or interest of the United States or for the benefit of any foreign government to the detriment of the United States any classified information [...]

The wording is slightly more complicated [than DoD's] including "uses in any manner prejudicial to the safety or interest of the United States". (Despite vaguely similar wording, this is technically not treason.)
But, again, it's rather hard to see a prosecutor initiating a case against someone arguing that they should have known that disclosing something to [e.g.] the (somewhat disabled) President was "prejudicial to the safety or interest of the United States", unless some extremely weird scenario then unfolded like the president ordered the military [or maybe just a diplomat] to do something outlandish and arguably "prejudicial ... to the US" [as a result of that info] and they too didn't protest etc. Still, it's hard for me to see a prosecutor 'scapegoating' the [initial] source of that info  [or rather them communicating it 'up the chain'] instead of those doing something [legally] dubious as a result of the president ordering something like that because of their diminished capacity. The benefit of the doubt [for that person/source] merely communicating something [to the president] would probably be hard to dispel, in court, in such a case, even in such a scenario when something demonstrably  "prejudicial to the safety or interest of the United States" came about as a result of further action stemming from the President. (Never mind that courts would probably punt on the assessment as 'political question' in debatable cases of what is 'prejudicial' [to the US].)
